# How ping is measured between two players?

Tags: networking, ping, traceroute

Say i have a ping of around 34-36ms to my ISP and my friend gets like for example 47ms, so if we got a different latency time from the same ISP and in the same town, if i\he host a match game.. what do you think pinging each other would look like? is it going to look like this 47+34=81ms? or is it going to be different? Recently i played with my neiborhood friend and i got 39-41ms to him which is only 4-7ms difference when pinging to my ISP, does that mean that it won't decrease/increase no matter what? Assuming he lives next to me?(i know that the further away the server is, the higher the ping/latency. So how about connecting to a hosting player? Is it the same thing as connecting to the server from the same location??)

hope you guys can answer that question, and Thnx for answering.

Best regards.

John Hark.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that my answer is not concrete.

**what do you think pinging each other would look like?**

The ping time depends on how the routing happens in the core network. From the edge network eye, we can't see far beyond in the network. So, if you ping your friend, i would say it will depend on how the network is routing it. If both of you are being served by same network ISP the probability of ping rtt will be less.

**is it going to look like this 47+34=81ms?**

Definitely it will not be 47+34, core routers have intelligent routing algorithms to give shorter routes.

**Recently i played with my neiborhood friend and i got 39-41ms to him which is only 4-7ms difference when pinging to my ISP, does that mean that it won't decrease/increase no matter what?**

No. It depends on many factors, is your friend and you being served by same ISP? are you both on same service level agreement with your ISP? If I have to speak in ms time resolution, even ping packet size and your time sync (ntp) and time stamping mechanism will also effect.

**So how about connecting to a hosting player? Is it the same thing as connecting to the server from the same location??)**

It depends on how your game is designed? is that a peer-to-peer game? or being served from game server?

Comment: Wow... Amazing! Thank you so much for taking your time to answer that question! I would like to vote up for this most ideal answer, but i don't have much reputaion so it can't be helped i guess xD.

Comment: Well about your question... I think it was a P2P game(GTA V) and there also a game that let gamers host their own match i think it was called "listen-server" which is a matchmaking process(Call of duty)

Comment: Not so sure about those games. However, P2P games involve direct communication, so you can expect them faster (in terms of network latency).

Comment: Oh nice. If you don't mind at all, i would like to ask one last more question: is a ping of 34ms to my ISP server/router is considered good? According to my tracert command, my packets go directly to the ISP servers which is only 1-3 hops which should be relatively lower than my current ping(10-20). Could it be that ISP has a bad routing when sending back the reply for packets? I'm pretty sure it's not due to low-priority or cogestion traffic, because the pings time are always stable and they do not change at all.

Comment: sorry of the delay. Not so sure if its considered good. I don't have/know any stats to compare with. I think its decently good. What is current ping(10-20 ) that you mean? For 2-3 hops; there might not be any bad routing. It might come into picture in larger context.

Comment: Oh, well never mind.. I got the problem! It's because my ISP put me on what they call "noise profile" which is an interleaving mode that corrects errors when receiving packets in DSLM  before passing them to my gateway router which adds small amounts of latency. I called the ISP tech support to switch me to a Fastpath mode and now my pings are cut in half when doing tracert to my first hops which returns with only 12ms!! :D

Comment: Cool Interesting things! :)